# Finding a formula for number of permutations satisfying pattern constraints

Tags: combinatorics, constraints

I'm trying to find a formula that gives the number of unique permutations of a set of 3 values of ***n*** length given a set of constraints.

**The values:** $-1, 0, 1$

**Example Set:** $[0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$

**the constraints:**

- '$-1$' must follow more '$1$'s than '$-1$'s

  - i.e: The sum of the values preceding a '$-1$' must be >= $0$
- '$-1$' must precede at least 2 '$1$'s

For instance, if given the example set above ($[0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$) there would be 12 valid permutations.

For any combination of '$1$'s and '$0$'s, as there are no constraints for those values, I am able to use the formula:

$$\frac{ N! }{
A! \cdot B! \cdot C! ... !
}$$

Where $N$ is the total length of the set and $A, B, C$ are the counts of each value in the set.

I have seen ways to implement simple constraints to this formula in the way of pairs, such that for the set $A, A{'}, B, B{'}$ for every item $X$: $X$ must come before $X{'}$.
However, I couldn't think of a way to apply the constraints I have to the formula.

Any help is appreciated, even if it's just that there is no way to do this. Thank you!

Comment: You're skirting on the edge of some very hard combinatorics. This problem might be solvable (i have no advice on that tonight, sorry), but modify it a little bit and it'll become #P-complete.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the difficulty of this, i thought i might just be missing something very simple. also... what exactly is #P-Complete? i see terms like that and NP-Complete thrown around Stack Exchange all the time and i'm not really sure how it applies.

Comment: It's computational complexity theory. A decision problem is in NP if it can be solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine in polynomial time (the machine "knows the right answer when it sees it" and can get it as quickly as possible). A counting problem is in #P if it counts the number of solutions to a polynomial time decision problem. A problem in a complexity class is "complete" if any other problem in the complexity class can be reduced to it in a certain way, so they're essentially the hardest problems in the complexity class.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That makes much more sense than what I'd come up with reading the wikipedia entries for both.

Comment: @user3693200 do you have any reason to believe this would be much easier than it looks? As I have reason to believe it might be.  If you do too for any reason then I might be tempted to have a go at solving it.

Comment: Ok here are my thoughts before I go to work for the day... the zeroes can go anywhere so let's pretend they don't exist for now.  Next, the $>=0$ rule is like saying each 1 is an open bracket and each -1 is a close bracket.  A close bracket can only follow if there are sufficient open brackets preceding it.  There is a maths that describes this, with intuitive diagrams and combinatorial rules all calculated for you - I can't remember its name but if you backtrack through John Baez's blog you will find it, the pictures look like mountain ranges.

Comment: The $>=0$ rule also means you only have valid solutions if there are no more $-1$'s than $1$'s  So take all $n$ -1's, permutate them with $n$ of the 1's using the "brackets" rule I describe above (if you can find it!), and then permutate how many ways the $0's$ can be placed among them with any location permitted.  Finally (and this is the tricky bit) permutate how many ways the remaining $1$'s can be distributed in what you have without creating any duplicates.

Comment: This last step will involve treating every string of 1's as a single position because no matter where within an existing string of 1's you place another 1, you have the same result.  This bit is a partitioning problem in which the 0's and -1's form the partitions and the strings of 1's are being partitioned among them. So the number of partitions is 1 plus the number of 0's plus the number of -1's. Even after establishing a good method, actually completing it and achieving an answer in which you have faith, will require some painstaking work.

Comment: Ok I dug out John Baez's post.  The combinatorics that govern the -1's and 1's in your rule is called Dyck words. The set of all such sets is called the Dyck language.  The number of Dyck words of length $2n$ is the $n^{th}$ Catalan number.

Comment: @Robert Frost, thank you, Dyck Language seems perfect for what i'm trying to accomplish.  However, as far as I can tell, Dyck Language can only account for an equal amount of each "parenthesis". I feel as though I could figure this out given the right direction, but as it stands currently my mathematical knowledge doesn't much extend into the realm of combinatorics.  After all, I only started delving into combinatorics a few days ago, but I need to find a solution to this problem. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @user3693200 out of interest, where did this problem come from? What does it signify?

Comment: @Robert Frost The permutations signify all valid movesets across a linear board where -1 is move back a tile, 0 is don't move, and 1 is move forward a tile. Hence the >=0 rule, because you cannot go further back than the starting point. And you may no longer move back after reaching the end, hence the need for -q to always proceed at least two 1s. The problem is the root of a programming problem I was given, however the most efficient and sensual way to complete this, I believe, is through combinatorics.

Comment: I was on my phone for the last comment, and I fat fingered so: "proceed" == "preceed", "-q" == "-1", and best of all "sensual" == "sensical"